# Multiple Instances of a JavaScript Rollover - Stopped Functioning

Tags: javascript, html

So, I've been using this JavaScript Snippet through out a fairly large website for rollovers:

```
<a href=http://www.barnesandnoble.com  onMouseOver= "if (document.images) document.bn_off.src= 'img/vendorbuttons/bn_on.gif';" onMouseOut= "if (document.images) document.bn_off.src= 'img/vendorbuttons/bn_off.gif';"><img src="img/vendorbuttons/bn_off.gif" name=bn_off border=0></a>
```

Which has worked great, and effortlessly, until now - I have a couple pages that will use the same rollover images for Buy Buttons across the pages, they will be the same aside from a different link being implemented. -Once I began using that JS, with using the same images more then once, all of the JS rollovers stopped work and don't render the 'off state'.

**Ultimately - apparently, I can't have multiple JS rollovers using the same images more then once with this code? Any suggestions?**

Comment: Gooing to hazard a guess and ask if you changed the name of the links on different pages?

Comment: why don't you use a css sprite for this now?

Comment: Well, I already have all the JS code from above set for every button - so if there was an easy fix within that code that'd be so much less time consuming. But yes, I probably should next time - Sprites are CS3 though, right?

Comment: Paddy - you mean name as in swapping out each link? If so, yes I've definitely done that - or do you mean name as in, name=bn_off should I change that, if so, won't it have to be the same as images being used, ultimately making me have to create new images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure nothing was changed? Images or code?
Since there isn't any clue here in the html (because you say it worked earlier), I can only suggest the following:

`href="http://www.barnesandnoble.com"` , `name="bn_off"` and `border="0"` <- these attribute values are missing double-quotes in your code.

Also try adding `id="bn_off"` (You already have `name="bn_off"`, keep that too).

EDIT:

I think I know why. Because you are copying and pasting this to use in multiple locations, you get multiple links with the SAME name `bn_off`, and that is why it stops working.

It could have been WAY more easier with jQuery and/or CSS but here's what you can do with what you have:

Add these two functions inside a `script` block in the `HEAD` section of your html:

```
    function OnMouseOver(link)
    {
        if (document.images)
        {
            var imageElements = link.getElementsByTagName("img");
            imageElements[0].src = 'img/vendorbuttons/bn_on.gif';
        }
    }

    function OnMouseOut(link)
    {
        if (document.images)
        {
            var imageElements = link.getElementsByTagName("img");
            imageElements[0].src = 'img/vendorbuttons/bn_off.gif';
        }
    }
```

Change your html for the links like this:

```
<a href="http://www.barnesandnoble.com" onMouseOver= "OnMouseOver(this);" onMouseOut= "OnMouseOut(this);">
    <img src="img/vendorbuttons/bn_off.gif" name="bn_off" border="0">
</a>
```

Now you can copy and paste the links as much as you want, the javascript won't depend on the name.

If I was you, I would use jQuery and CSS to simplify things.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but neither worked. The ones I have implemented without multiple instances, work without double quotes around those areas - also, the code is unchanged and works before copying and pasting it attempting to use in multiple instances with same images (different links) - it's pretty odd.

Comment: @LouieLouie77 I have edited my answer, this will fix your problem (I tested). Make sure you add the two functions inside a `script` block in the `HEAD` section of your html.

Answer (score 0):

this is how to fix your existing script. However, Guganeshan's solution is much cleaner.

```
<a href=http://www.barnesandnoble.com  onMouseOver= "if (document.images) this.src= 'img/vendorbuttons/bn_on.gif';" onMouseOut= "if (document.images) this.src= 'img/vendorbuttons/bn_off.gif';"><img src="img/vendorbuttons/bn_off.gif" border=0></a>
```